# Proof of inequality using a limit

Tags: limits, inequality

I'm trying to prove the following inequality, but fails. 
$n$ goes to infinity.

$$c*n^3\leq (\log(n)) !   /:n^3$$
$$c\leq \frac{(\log(n)) !}{n^3} $$

When c constant. Need some $n_0$ after that happens forever.
I tried to think of it as a limit, that I look for what happens when the very large n.

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\frac{n^3}{(\log(n))!}=0$$

THANK YOU!

Comment: The notation is not clear. Do you mean $\log(n!)$? Maybe not, since $\frac{n^3}{\log(n!)}$ is large when $n$ is large. Or is it $(\log n)!$? But for $n\gt 1$ the (natural) logarithm is not an integer.

Comment: I mean to $(logn)!$ I think we can think about it as $(logn)!\epsilon \mathbb{Z}$ or floor of $(logn)!$

Comment: one can produce a version of the problem using the gamma function, or alternately we can use the floor or ceiling function on $\log n$ before taking the factorial.

Answer (score 0):

$\log n$ is not an integer for $1<n\in N.$ Let $[x]$ denote the largest integer not exceeding $x .$

For $n\geq 3$  we have $1\leq[\log n]<\log n.$ For brevity let $f(n)=[\log n].$

For $n\geq 3$ we have $$n^3/(f(n))!=(e^{\log n})^3/(f(n))! <(e^{1+f(n)})^3/(f(n))!=e^{3+3 f(n)}/(f(n))!.$$ Since $f(n)$ is an integer and increases monotonically to $\infty$ as $n\to \infty,$ it suffices to show that $g(m)=e^{3+3 m}/m! \to 0$ as integer $m\to \infty.$ We have (obviously) $g(m)>0$, and for $m>2 e^3-1$ we have $$g(m+1)=e^3 g(m)/(m+1)<g(m)/2.$$ 
Remark: We could also replace $[\log n]$ with $h(\log n)$ where $h(x)=\int_0^{\infty}u^xe^{-u}\;du$,  as $h$ is monotonic and $h(m)=m!$ for non-negative integer $m.$